# Show/Hide Div On Click (numerous Divs)

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

Scenario:

I have a state map of the USA.  Over top of the state map, I have manufactured an area map to make each state a clickable link.  Over each state, I have a `<div>` with absolute position and CSS styling to make the `<div>` look like a callout or tooltip box -- containing information about the address and website of the head office in each specific state.

So, yes, I have 50 different `<div>`s with absolute positioning that are currently set to "visibility:hidden".

**What I am trying to accomplish:**

When you click on a specific link from the area map, the `<div>` for that US state will appear in the appropriate location.  Furthermore, when you click on the exact same state the `<div>` will hide, or when you click on a different state the all of the `<div>`s hide, and the proper `<div>` for the new state will appear.

I would prefer to do this in simple Javascript (not Jquery) as ultimately the page will be loaded in a website with a Drupal CMS.

Please help.  I'd rather not code each state as a button and write fifty different segments of javascript code.

Comment: Why no jQuery? Doesn't Drupal already comes with jQuery?

Comment: Why don't you think to do it with CSS?

Comment: @LieRyan with my drupal, I'm using a modified javascript & jquery profile to help overcome a programming issue with one of my modules.  It's a workaround, but it works.

Comment: @Faith If i do it in straight javascript I can call it easily as an external file with the drupal node and again it won't disrupt the module workaround I stated above.   Plus, when it comes to Jquery... I kinda suck.

Comment: And I really don't have any working code to post.  I've tried many different scenarios, including one REALLY long jQuery attempt (50 different functions each listing a show or hide funtion for each div, so it would be about 2600 lines long.)

Comment: For anyone helping me out on this --- my areamap <id>s for each state are "StateMI" for Michigan, "StateCA" for california, "StateNC" for North Carolina, etc.

For my hidden <div>s, the div name follows the same naming protocal.  i.e.  layerCA for California, layerWA for Washington, layerFL for Florida., etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have three main problems to solve:

1. enumerate all the links
2. attach the onclick event handlers to those links
3. map the links to the divs

You can enumerate the links with the .getElement* functions. Depending on the markup of your list, it might take a more walk around before you get the elements you want; jQuery would really help in simplifying the .getElement* functions.

Next, you attach onclick handler to each of those links. You can do this by assigning to the element.onclick attribute. This is the key part to writing "unobtrusive javascript", which are used heavily in jQuery.

Finally, you need a way to map the links to the divs. The simplest is to build the id of the target div using the links' id. So, for example, if a link's id is 'io' (for Iowa) then you will toggle the visibility of the div whose id is 's_io' by simply prepending 's_' to the link's id. Alternatively, you can use a hash map or HTML 5 custom data attribute to store the id of the target div or you can use str.replace or str.substring.

You can see this in action in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/berqK/), [another version using image map](http://jsfiddle.net/berqK/2/).

Comment: I like the overall idea.  I am having trouble applying your example to the image map though.  You can see a working example at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ccraiff/wDxuC/).  Maybe you can see what I am missing.  In the example there are only two states image mapped out (Washington and oregon, upper left corner)

Comment: @CCRaiff: see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/berqK/4/), it is based on my second version that uses image map.

Comment: @CCRaiff: what you missed is that you didn't change the id for the list of links/areas in the javascript: `var links = document.getElementById('oshastatemap');`

Answer (score 1):

I would change your design slightly and use a single `div` for displaying the state info. Store the state info another way (I used `dataset-` values in my sample and used the state name as the `class`) and load it dynamically into your info `div`. This makes it easier to show/hide when clicking on the same state, and is less markup. Also, use `display: none;` to hide the state info `div` so it's removed from the layout.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/WYLzY/

Script:

```js
var areas = document.getElementsByTagName( 'area' );

for( var index = 0; index < areas.length; index++ ) {    

    areas[index].addEventListener( 'click', function ( event ) {

        var info = document.getElementById( 'info' ), display;

        if( info.hasClass( this.dataset.state ) ) {
            display = info.style.display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
        } else {
            info.setAttribute( 'class', this.dataset.state );
            display = 'block';
        } 

        info.innerHTML = this.dataset.address;
        info.style.display = display;

    }, false );

};

Element.prototype.hasClass = function ( className ) {
    return this.className.split( ' ' ).indexOf( className ) > -1;
};
```

HTML:

```html
<div id="map-view">
<img id="map" src="http://thinkingstiff.com/images/matt.jpg" usemap="#map"/>
<map name="map">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,50,50" data-state="california" 
    data-address="123 One St&lt;br /&gt;Chronic Town, CA 99190" href="#" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="50,50,150,150" data-state="oregon" 
    data-address="345 Two St&lt;br /&gt;Bird On It, OR 89190" href="#" />
</map>
<div id="info"></div>
<div>
```

CSS:

```css
#map {
    height: 245px;
    width: 180px;
}

#map-view {
    position: relative;
}

#info {
    background-color: white;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.california {
    left: 50px;
    top: 25px;
}

.oregon {
    left: 150px;
    top: 125px;
}
```